# PHP WebSite : How to manage timers?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, timer, server

With a friend we want to develop a php game like ogame (like a huuuuuge amount of people). To avoid breaking our tooth we started by takink a lot of time designing the website and thinking about technologies to use and how to adapt it to our site.
But we found a huge problem we are not sure to know how to solve it that's why I am here.
First, I have learnt ogame is a "php server game" so we choosen Symfony technology to begin with (have a solid structure and an evolutive code etc...).
But the game will have to be quite dynamic, we thought Angular JS could help us to make it dynamic without having to refresh the page (animations etc...).

However we thought about how to store our informations and at the begining, storing users and ships and units wasn't the most complicated. But storing timers and interceptions/fights between fleets and armies at end of a timer (corresponding to a move) has highlighted a new problem : how to do it ?

To be as precise as possible : we think it will be necessary to execute php code continuously on the server, like in objects languages as C++ but we don't know how to do it.

We certainly have a lack of knowledge about a web technology that will solve it or a way to store those timers (kind of structure).

As a resume, here an example of our problematic :

The player is sending an army to (x,y) and it will take 3600s. A php object could look like "army_move" describing the army, the destination, the date of arriving etc...
Angular (or other JS code) displays the countdown (1h 00min 00s - 0h 59min 59s - ...). If the player stops the move the army come back (simple request to server that changes the object in the database). But if the army finaly manage to attack the target, what happen ? how ?
In our opinion the server has to check the timers continuously to know when to send the fight repports, make the fights etc... but it's php so how to do it ?
Moreover, how to be sure the solution will has enough accuracy to manage entries / attacks when the players try to attack themselves at one second ? The system must not lose any second while processing.
We thought timers stored into databases could be a solution, but obviously it will take too much processing strenght and we would know which solution is brought by games like ogame, travian etc...
Does anyone know a structure / technology to help us ? We searched and found nothing, however we might not type the right keywords, so documentation about it would be welcomed :)

Thanks fo reading me and all my apologizes for my english, I hope I've been understood and wait for your answers :) (or questions).

Answer (score 0):

Php is a serverside script that starts after every new request coming from a client and ends a few microseconds later, just while the response is sent back to the client. In this short time information can be read from the database or written to the database. Then, there could be a period for minutes, hours or even months before a new request (of the same user) will come again. A timer on a server or in a database is therefor nonsense. Instead you should store the actual time into the database at each request and calculate the time difference between the actual request and the previous request. You could use a timer in javascript but of course that does not give you any information about the other player(s). If you really need to know the position (for example) from other players at any moment then you could think about [websockets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm).

Comment: Websocket using a php script instead of Python script: [Link](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your first structure, what would trigger the resolution of the fight on the server ? The game must be running on the server independently of the clients requests.